# Email To Case not working fine - Case is creating, but not get assign to web-to-case queue why?

Tags: email2case

I am trying to implement the Email-to-case in Salesforce for that I created email-to-case **Queue** like below. The case is getting created, but I dont see Web `Origine = Email` coming when I send email to that emailId. Please guide whats wrong

[image]

**Then I created email-to-case like below.**

[image]

**Email TO Case Routing Information..**

[image]

**And I created New View**

[image]

[image]

The highlighted case is getting created, but its not under email-to-case view...

[image]

Comment: do you have InboundEmailHandler class?

Comment: Then verify if assignment rule exists

Comment: yes, you can omit based on certain condition. Also, the address is not verified at your screenshot (Email-to-Case routing information). Verify the address and it will work. If that works, I will put that as ans

Comment: Yes, after verification of email its working fine..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per **Santanu**, you must not need to create an `Assignment rule` still depends upon the certion condition. I had not verified the email address (as you can see it in screen shots). After verification of email address. Its working fine. I attached screen shot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see the address is not verified at your screenshot (Email-to-Case routing information).

**Verify the address and it will work.**